# How to target file with %20 in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Here is my .htaccess:

```
...
rewriterule file%20name.htm http://mysite.com/new_name.htm#anchor [r=301,nc,ne]
...
```

It's not redirected, and I believe this is because it's not targeting the file with the %20 in the name. As for the flags, I used ne to not rewrite the #anchor portion of the redirect.

Also, the flag "nu" breaks my file and I get internal server 500 error.

Thanks you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `mod_rewrite` is invoked, the path has already been decoded as part of Apache's request processing. So, if you want to check for a space, you can do so literally:

```
RewriteRule file\ name\.html http://example.com/new_name.htm#anchor [R=301,NC,NE,L]
```

The `NU` flag [doesn't exist](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule), which is why you get an internal server error when you try to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best answer, and can only be used in specific cases, but I changed

```
file%20name.htm
```

to

```
file.*
```

so it will match any filename that starts with "file", regardless of spaces and special chars.